# How to use an UPDATE within the IF ELSE SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to check if a column exists within a given table.

When checking if it exists, I want to update the column with the value 1, if not, create and update.

However, every time I run the error, the column still does not exist.

In the runtime, it first considers my update to the alter table.

To illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM BANCO_DE_DADOS.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            WHERE (TABLE_NAME) = 'MinhaTabela' 
            AND  (COLUMN_NAME) = 'CodZona'  )  

BEGIN
    UPDATE BANCO_DE_DADOS..MinhaTabela 
    SET CodZona = 1 
    WHERE CodZona < 1 OR CodZona IS NULL    
END

ELSE
BEGIN 

    ALTER TABLE BANCO_DE_DADOS..MinhaTabela
    ADD  [CodZona] [int] NULL

    UPDATE BANCO_DE_DADOS..MinhaTabela 
    SET CodZona = 1

END
```

Error:

```
Message 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'CodZona'.
Message 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'CodZona
```

'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is compiling versus executing queries.  The error arises during compilation.

You can do:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM BANCO_DE_DADOS.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
               WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MinhaTabela' AND
                     COLUMN_NAME = 'CodZona'
              ) 
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql N'ALTER TABLE BANCO_DE_DADOS..MinhaTabela ADD [CodZona] [int] NULL';
END; 
GO

update BANCO_DE_DADOS..MinhaTabela
    set CodZona = 1
    where CodZona < 1 or CodZona is null;
```

Comment: Right. I did this procedure and had the following return.

`Message 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
The procedure expects the parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext / nchar / nvarchar'.`

Comment: @RafaelCarlos . . . It requires that the SQL string be `NVARCHAR()` and doesn't convert it.  It just needs the `N` prefix.